# Why does my web2py app keep logging me out

Tags: python, web2py

I recently deployed a web2py app, and am going through the debugging phase. Part of the app includes an `auth.wiki`, which mostly works great. Last night I added several pages to the wiki with no problems.

However, today, whenever I navigate to the wiki or try to edit a page, I'm immediately logged out.

Any suggestions? I can't interact with the wiki if I'm not logged in...

EDIT: It's not just the wiki, I keep getting logged out of the whole site. Other users do not have this problem. It continues even when I select "remember me for 30 days" on login.

Comment: This seems only to happen when I've also logged into admin in this browser session.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment hints at the answer: When you log into the admin session, when you refresh your website, it is now accessed through the admin session, which has no client user logged in.

One solution is to use different browsers for admin and a different browser for client.